# How to load javascript file in apache wicket?

Tags: javascript, json, resources, wicket

I have a javascript file in my web application that uses the eval(jsonString) Method. Eval() because I am working with JSON too.

My javascript file is inside a package in netbeans. What should I do to make my javascript file globally aviable for the application and browser?

*The problem:* The eval method won't start because the .js file is not recongnized by the browser. JSON.parse(..) does not work too.

So: How do I correctly add this javascript file to my web application. So I can manipulate it by the web application during runtime and execute the eval Method?

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Why are you using a browser so old that it doesn't recognize the JSON object? Is that a requirement?

Comment: I got the newest firefox browser. This is not the problem. I have to load the resource into the web application framework called wicket correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load resources (javascript) in a web application framework (wicket) correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443361/load-resources-javascript-in-a-web-application-framework-wicket-correctly)

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you are searching?

```
private static final ResourceReference JS = new JavaScriptResourceReference(YourPage.class, "path/to/js");

@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(response);
    response.render(JavaScriptReferenceHeaderItem.forReference(JS));
}
```

Put that into your page class.

Comment: Yes I tried that. But I also use the .js file by other java classes. Is this JS resource shared and is it dynamically, so other classes can use it, modify it and it updates automatically?

Comment: The relevant part that answers your question is "Put that into your page class." because this will share the resource for all sub-classes of this page. You should use an abstract base class for all your pages to achieve this the easiest way.

Comment: Yes, but I have different packages in netbeans. Where should I put the javascript file then? should I create a new folder, use existing resource folder? And how should the "path/to/js" look like? "resources/js" would be ok?

Comment: I opened a new post describing my problem better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443361/load-resources-javascript-in-a-web-application-framework-wicket-correctly#comment18380187_13443361 .. maybe u can answer there too..