# Load resources (javascript) in a web application framework (wicket) correctly?

Tags: javascript, reference, resources, load, wicket

I am using Apache Wicket as my webapp framework and I have a following structure:
[image]

What I need:

1) The javascript file Rules.js should be loaded and readable for my Custom Java Class Process.java. Because in my Process.java I have something like this:

```
private String readFile(String filename) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("PATH");
    //reads the file and returns a string
    ...
}
```

**So the first question would be: What path instead of "PATH" should I use, when my resource Rules.js is in the resource folder or any other package folder?**

2) The Process.java not only reads the file, it also manipulates my Rules.js file for example with json. So the following line should be added to the Rules.js file:

```
var object = {JSON STRING};
```

I know how to do this already.

3) After the manipulation of the Rules.js file it should automatically be updated of course. 
**So the second question would be: What else should I add and where to my application so the Rules.js is a file that is aviable for all needed classes in my application and is always up to date during the session.**

I tried a lot of things already, but I am missing here something that I cant figure out...

Comment: Ey, first you are opening many questions for the same reason... so please close the other questions.

Comment: And as I commented you in the other question may be you need to generate dynamically the rules.js file, and not try to modify any file.

Comment: nah the rules.js cant just be generated dynamically. users will need it to define their rules inside this file. yea. yes I will close the other question once I know how....

Comment: So each user will have his own rules.js?

Comment: You can create your rules.js wherever you want and load it using your own AbstractResource that points to this/those files.

Comment: @jordeu nono. There is one rules.js with a rule like if(price>100).. every company uses a different rules.js. So its one rules.js per web application. Another company can have another rules.js... I think AbstractResource goes in the right direction. but its so hard to find tutorials for that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own `IResource` or even use the `ContextRelativeResource` if you want to keep your `rules.js` file on the webapp root.

At your `WebApplication` you have to register the resource as a shared resource:

```
    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        getSharedResources().add(RULES_RESOURCE_KEY, new ContextRelativeResource(RULES_CONTEXT_FILE));
    }

    public static ResourceReference getRulesResourceReference() {
        return Application.get().getSharedResources().get(Application.class, RULES_RESOURCE_KEY, null, null, null, true);
    }
```

Here an example method that modifies the `rules.js` file.

```
    public static void changeRules() {    
        try {
            // Get a context URL
            URL rules = WebApplication.get()
                     .getServletContext()
                     .getResource(RULES_CONTEXT_FILE);

            // Update the file
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(rules.toURI())));
            out.write("var rules=\"" + Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "\" ");
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WicketRuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
```

At your `HomePage` class or wherever you need update the `rules.js`:

```
    public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);

        add(new Link("changerules") {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                WicketApplication.changeRules();
            }
        });
    }
```

At the page that you have your `Form` add a `JavaScriptHeaderItem`:

```
    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        response.render(
                JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(WicketApplication.getRulesResourceReference())
        );
    }
```

The HTML to run this example if you want to test it:

```
    <html>
        <body onload="alert(rules);">
            <a wicket:id="changerules" href="#">Change rules files</a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

And don't forget to create an initial version of `rules.js` at your `webapp` folder.

I think that it's **not** a good idea to update the files in the `webapp` folder, because the container can replace it for the initial version at redeploy time. So it's better to use your own IResource and put the file in an external folder. Check this [post](http://dotev.blogspot.com.es/2009/11/serving-images-and-other-resources-with.html) if you need more details.

Comment: Thank you! I am tryin it out now. But what is the difference between RULES_RESOURCE_KEY and RULES_CONTEXT_FILE. I used "Rules.js" for the KEY and "rules" for the FILE. And the Rules.js file is in the same package folder as my InvoiceForm.

Comment: Here I got a problem:  URL rules = MyWebApplication.get().getServletContext().getResource("Rules.js"); It says "Path Rules.js does not start with '/'". But when I put "/Rules.js" it gives me a NullPointException.

Comment: You can use RULES_CONTEXT_FILE as a key if you want. The RULES_CONTEXT_FILE is the relative path to your file in webapp folder (starting with a /). You have to create the file in webapp.

Comment: Yes, it brought me to the right direction ;) But I did not try it out to 100% because the assistant told me that its not really needed, I should modify the javascript file only during runtime, so I used Rhino like I did before, and with Rhino I called the functions that I need. Also the eval function of JSON.